# css heading tags "standards"?

Tags: margin, font-size, css, html-heading

I'm looking for a way to standardize my h1, h2, h3, etc tags after I apply a css reset, I know this mostly depends on the design but I remember seeing in a site that there was some sort of "golden ratio" between the text size, line-height and margin-bottom that would improve readability and better the way headers looked on the page.

Do any of you know anything like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this depends a great deal on the font used.  That said, *Smashing Magazine* gives this "rule of thumb":

> **Heading to Body Font-Size Ratio**
>
> To better understand the relationship
>   between heading and body font size, we
>   divided each website’s heading font
>   size by its body font size. We took
>   the average of these ratios and
>   derived a rule of thumb for you to
>   work with:
>
> Heading font size ÷ Body copy font
>   size = 1.96
>
> The overall value, then, is 1.96. This
>   means that when you have chosen a font
>   size for your body copy, you may want
>   to multiply it by 2 to get your
>   heading font size. This, of course,
>   depends on your style; the rule of
>   thumb won’t necessarily give you the
>   optimal size for your particular
>   design. Another option is to use a
>   traditional scale (6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
>   12, 14, 16, 18, 21, 24, 36, 48, 60,
>   72) or the Fibonacci sequence (e.g. 16
>   – 24 – 40 – 64 – 104) to get natural
>   typographic results.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/20/typographic-design-survey-best-practices-from-the-best-blogs/

Comment: Yeah I figured it would be a very site-specific question, thanks for the link though!